# Conditional command line arguments in Python using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I'd like to have a program that takes a `--action=` flag, where the valid choices are `dump` and `upload`, with `upload` being the default.  If (and only if) `dump` is selected, I'd like there to also be a `--dump-format=` option.  Is there a way to express this using argparse, or do I need to just accept all the arguments and do the logic myself.

Comment: Is it a viable option (aesthetically speaking) to do something like `--action=dump-csv` or `--action=dump-some-other-format`? This would alleviate the problem of having "required options" entirely.

Comment: @dcrosta it would obviously work, but I prefer not to go that way, I find it unwieldy.

Comment: Fair enough, just wanted to make sure you've covered the obvious bases.

Comment: He needed default to be upload -- parser.add_argument('--action', choices=['upload', 'dump'], default='dump') but I did not think of parser.error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use [`parser.error`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.error):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--action', choices=['upload', 'dump'], default='dump')
parser.add_argument('--dump-format')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.action != 'dump' and args.dump_format:
    parser.error('--dump-format can only be set when --action=dump.')
```

Comment: This is only describing the "argparse way" of reporting an error. The logic is implemented manually.  Not an "argparse" way of conditionally requiring arguments.

Comment: If instead of "dump" and "format" there are 5 more options that all have their own set of required or non-required arguments this way of checking for requiredness can get unclear fast.

Comment: Besides, things like argparse.FileType will get problems. For certain selected actions when the FileType argument is not needed, non-existence of the file causes a false error.

Answer (score 81):

The argparse module offers a way to do this without implementing your own
requiredness checks. The example below uses "subparsers" or "sub commands".
I've implemented a subparser for "dump" and one for "format".

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('file', help='The file you want to act on.')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='subcommand')
subparsers.required = True  # required since 3.7

#  subparser for dump
parser_dump = subparsers.add_parser('dump')
# add a required argument
parser_dump.add_argument(
    'format',
    choices=['csv', 'json'],
    help='Dump the file in this format.')

#  subparser for upload
parser_upload = subparsers.add_parser('upload')
# add a required argument
parser_upload.add_argument(
    'server',
    choices=['amazon', 'imgur'],
    help='Upload the file to this service.')

args = parser.parse_args()
print args
if args.subcommand == 'dump':
    print 'I will now dump "%s" in the %s format' % (args.file, args.format)
if args.subcommand == 'upload':
    print 'I will now upload "%s" to %s' % (args.file, args.server)
```

That looks like this on the command line:

```
$ python ap.py 
usage: ap.py [-h] file {upload,dump} ...
ap.py: error: too few arguments

$ python ap.py tmp.txt 
usage: ap.py [-h] file {upload,dump} ...
ap.py: error: too few arguments
```

Upload:

```
$ python ap.py tmp.txt upload
usage: ap.py file upload [-h] {amazon,imgur}
ap.py file upload: error: too few arguments

$ python ap.py tmp.txt upload amazo
usage: ap.py file upload [-h] {amazon,imgur}
ap.py file upload: error: argument server: invalid choice: 'amazo' (choose from 'amazon', 'imgur')

$ python ap.py tmp.txt upload amazon
Namespace(file='tmp.txt', server='amazon', subcommand='upload')
I will now upload "tmp.txt" to amazon

$ python ap.py tmp.txt upload imgur
Namespace(file='tmp.txt', server='imgur', subcommand='upload')
I will now upload "tmp.txt" to imgur
```

Dump:

```
$ python ap.py tmp.txt dump
usage: ap.py file dump [-h] {csv,json}
ap.py file dump: error: too few arguments

$ python ap.py tmp.txt dump csv
Namespace(file='tmp.txt', format='csv', subcommand='dump')
I will now dump "tmp.txt" in the csv format

$ python ap.py tmp.txt dump json
Namespace(file='tmp.txt', format='json', subcommand='dump')
I will now dump "tmp.txt" in the json format
```

More info: [`ArgumentParser.add_subparsers()`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers)

Comment: The design of the command line arguments are different than the one asked.

Comment: Doesn't python `print` require `()`? Why is it not used above? It errors when I run the example above because `print` tells me the syntax should be `print('something')` rather than `print 'something'`. Is this an environment specific quirk? (I am running in Windows)

Comment: @skeetastax `print` worked like that in Python 2, this answer is from 2012 when Python 2 was still common.

Answer (score 43):

Another way to approach the problem is by using [subcommands](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) (a'la git) with "action" as the first argument:

```
script dump --dump-format="foo"
script upload
```

Comment: One limitation is that `argparse` does not allow multiple `subparsers`.

Comment: This is wrong. You can add as many subparsers as you want. See subcommands link referenced in answer. See also [Niels Bom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13706448/2311167)

Comment: ... or did you mean _nesting_ of subcommands? Something like `dump dumpsubcommand1` , `dump subcommand2`, `upload subcommand3` etc..?

Answer (score 6):

It depends what you consider "doing all the logic yourself". You can still use argparse and add the dump option as follows with minimal effort without resorting to sub-commands:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from sys import argv

parser = ArgumentParser()
action_choices = ['upload', 'dump']
parser.add_argument('--action', choices=action_choices, default=action_choices[1])
parser.add_argument('--dump-format', required=(action_choices[1] in argv))
```

This way argparse won't care about the dump format if the dump action wasn't selected

Comment: That's clever, elegant solution for specific usecases

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Suppose you have a tool that lists, adds and deletes records in a table with the following structure:

| id | sitekey | response | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456 | valid | a |
| 2 | 234567 | invalid |  |
| 3 | 345678 | invalid | c |
| 4 | 456789 | valid | d |

And you want to have the following operations and arguments:

- list

  - from: optional
  - to: optional
  - short-response: optional
- add

  - sitekey: required
  - response: required
  - status: optional
- remove

  - id: required

Then, you can have a code similar to the following:

```
import argparse
import sys

operation_choices = ['list', 'add', 'remove']
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--operation",
                    choices = operation_choices,
                    default = operation_choices[0],
                    help = "Your help!",
                    required = True)

# list operation subarguments
if True in list(map(lambda x: operation_choices[0] in x, sys.argv)):
    parser.add_argument("--from",
                        type = int,
                        default = 1,
                        help = "Your help!",
                        required = False)
    parser.add_argument("--to",
                        type = int,
                        help = "Your help!",
                        required = False)
    parser.add_argument("--short-response",
                        type = bool,
                        default = True,
                        help = "Your help!",
                        required = False)

# add operation subarguments
if True in list(map(lambda x: operation_choices[1] in x, sys.argv)):
    parser.add_argument("--sitekey",
                        type = str,
                        help = "Your help!",
                        required = True)
    parser.add_argument("--response",
                        type = str,
                        help = "Your help!",
                        required = True)
    parser.add_argument("--status",
                        type = str,
                        help = "Your help!",
                        required = False)

# remove operation subarguments
if True in list(map(lambda x: operation_choices[2] in x, sys.argv)):
    parser.add_argument("--id",
                        type = int,
                        help = "Your help!",
                        required = True)

args = parser.parse_args()

# Your operations...
```

So when you run:

```
$ python tool.py --operation=list

This run, no required arguments

$ python tool.py --operation=add

usage: tool.py [-h] --operation {list,add,remove} --sitekey SITEKEY --response RESPONSE [--status STATUS]
tool.py: error: the following arguments are required: --sitekey, --response

$ python tool.py --operation=remove

usage: tool.py [-h] --operation {list,add,remove} --id ID
tool.py: error: the following arguments are required: --id

$ python tool.py --help

usage: tool.py [-h] --operation {list,add,remove}

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --operation {list,add,remove}
                        Your help!

$ python tool.py --operation=list --help

usage: tool.py [-h] --operation {list,add,remove} [--from FROM] [--to TO] [--short-response SHORT_RESPONSE]

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --operation {list,add,remove}
                        Your help!
  --from FROM           Your help!
  --to TO               Your help!
  --short-response SHORT_RESPONSE
                        Your help!

$ python tool.py --operation=add --help

usage: tool.py [-h] --operation {list,add,remove} --sitekey SITEKEY --response RESPONSE [--status STATUS]

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --operation {list,add,remove}
                        Your help!
  --sitekey SITEKEY     Your help!
  --response RESPONSE   Your help!
  --status STATUS       Your help!

$ python tool.py --operation=remove --help

usage: tool.py [-h] --operation {list,add,remove} --id ID

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --operation {list,add,remove}
                        Your help!
  --id ID               Your help!
```