# Requiring flags based upon other flags argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have a series of flags...

```
--one
--two

-a
-b
-c
-d
```

I would like to have -a and -b required whenever I start with --one and -c, -d whenever I start with --two.

How exactly do I accomplish this? I know I can make an option required, but that's not the same as requiring options based on already given options.

Comment: I think this question answers your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505898/conditional-command-line-arguments-in-python-using-argparse

Comment: It's probably simpler to check this yourself after parsing, or find an interface that's simpler and does not require *flags* at all (e.g. subcommands).

Comment: birryree, that post lead me to the answer, thanks! So, what's the protocol for a question like this then? Do I just delete it?