# conditional args parse in python

Tags: python, parsing, args

I would like to have a code that get the first argument as tool and after that expects different options depending on the tool

myapp.py [TOOL] [TOOLPARAMETERS]

`python myapp.py tool0 -i 'path/to/my_image.jpg' -o 'path/to/my_output_path_folder/' -r 0.7 -m 13`

`python myapp.py tool1 -m 3 -r 'some_string_now' -m 13`

As you can see in this case each tool could have it's own required arguments and in each case they could even expect different types

I have been messing around with `add_subparsers` with some success.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='myapp', usage='%(prog)s [tool] [options]')

parser.add_argument('-a', required=True, help='required globally argument for all tools')

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='tool help')

#  subparser for tool0
parser_tool0 = subparsers.add_parser('tool0', help='tool 0 help')

# ADD tool0 ARGUMENTS
parser_tool0.add_argument('-i' , required=True, help='path to the input folder')
parser_tool0.add_argument('-o' , required=True, help='path to the output folder')
parser_tool0.add_argument('-r' , default=0.7,   type=float, help='some float')
parser_tool0.add_argument('-g' , default=10,    type=int, help='some integrer')
parser_tool0.add_argument('-d' , default=False, help='debug')


#  subparser for tool1
parser_tool0 = subparsers.add_parser('tool1', help='tool 0 help')

# ADD tool0 ARGUMENTS
parser_tool0.add_argument('-r' , help='r not required string')
parser_tool0.add_argument('-f' , required=True, help='f not required string')
parser_tool0.add_argument('-d' , default=0.7,   type=float, help='some float')
parser_tool0.add_argument('-i' , default=10,    type=int, help='some integrer')
parser_tool0.add_argument('-b' , default=False, help='boolean')
parser_tool0.add_argument('opts',
                        help='Modify config options using the command-line',
                        default=None, nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

So I would like to know what should be the best practices for that case.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers) and this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505898/conditional-command-line-arguments-in-python-using-argparse) `subparsers` are the way to go.