# How can I set up argparse to parse either 'diff -g file1 -r file2' or 'format file'?

Tags: python, argparse

I want to use `argparse` to parse command line arguments for my program. The program supports two modes - `diff` and `format`.

When `-diff` is chosen, the arguments `-g <file1>` and `-r <file2>` are also needed. When `-format` is chosen, instead there should be a `<file>` argument.

How can I set up this logic with `argparse`? Should I use subparsers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional command line arguments in Python using argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505898/conditional-command-line-arguments-in-python-using-argparse)

Comment: Thank you! Not exactly the same but close.

Comment: In general, you should make `diff` and `format` subcommands, with subparsers, instead of being options themselves. That is, `foo diff` and `foo format`, instead of `foo -diff` and `foo -format`.

Comment: ...the standard way to parse `foo -diff` has it be identical to `foo -f -f -i -d`; that is to say, a collection of separate one-character flags, not a single world (hence the GNU extension `foo --diff` to make "diff" a word)

Comment: (see section 12.2 of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap12.html re: above assertion; when I say "standard", I _do_ mean formally-ratified-by-a-standards-body type "standard").

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you very much for the helps. I am looking into subparsers too but at the same time I found the last proposed one from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505898/conditional-command-line-arguments-in-python-using-argparse is a pretty good alternative apart from subparsers. It applies conditions on the top level parser instead of using subparser. It also provides a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just to share and record what I have finalized eventually.
There are two solutions that I tried and eventually I picked up the subparser one although I think both ways work well to suit this task:

1. Using subparser

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command')
subparsers.required = True

# subparser for diff
parser_multi = subparsers.add_parser('diff')
# add required arguments
parser_diff.add_argument(
    '-f1',
    '--file1',
    type=str,
    required=True
)
parser_diff.add_argument(
    '-f2',
    '--file2',
    type=str,
    required=True
)

# subparser for format
parser_format = subparsers.add_parser('format')
# add a required argument
parser_format.add_argument(
    '-f',
    '--file',
    type=str,
    required=True
)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

2. Using conditional args parser

```
import argparse
import sys

mode_choices = ['diff', 'format']
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-m',
                    '--mode',
                    choices=mode_choices,
                    help='Choose mode to start',
                    required=True)

if True in list(map(lambda x: mode_choices[0] in x, sys.argv)):
    parser.add_argument('-f1',
                        '--file1',
                        type=str,
                        required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-f2',
                        '--file2',
                        type=str,
                        required=True)

if True in list(map(lambda x: mode_choices[1] in x, sys.argv)):
    parser.add_argument('-f',
                        '--file',
                        type=str,
                        required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have two "modes" that each needs to enforce different optional and/or positional parameters I think your best bet would be to use subparsers for each of the modes...  Then you can either test the output namespace for which command was triggered or you can set default callables to trigger for each of the options:

Here is an example of what it could look like using this strategy.

```
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(sys.argv[0], prefix_chars="-")
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest="cmd")
diff_parser = subparsers.add_parser("diff", help='diff help')
diff_parser.add_argument(
    "-g",
    metavar="<file1>",
    action="store",
    dest="gfile",
    help="g help"
)
diff_parser.add_argument(
    "-r",
    metavar="<file2>",
    action="store",
    dest="rfile",
    help="r help"
)
format_parser = subparsers.add_parser("format", help="format help")
format_parser.add_argument(
    "file",
    metavar="<file>",
    help="file help"
)
args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

Then if you wanted to use a conditional to check which command was triggered like this:

```
if args["cmd"] == "diff":
    do something...
elif args["cmd"] == "format":
    do something else....
```

Or using default callables like this:

```
diff_parser.set_defaults(func=my_diff_func)

format_parser.set_defaults(func=my_format_func)

args.func(args)
```